# implements ListModel, need to update JList on Change

Tags: java, jlist, listmodel

I have a custom collection which implements `ListModel`. When this collection changes, i need to notify the `JList`. Typically you'd `fireListDataChanged`, but this is not a method implemented by `ListModel`.

How should I go about modifying my code to automatically update the `JList`?

JList here:

```
this.selectedInterfacesJList.setModel(new TufinInterfaceCollection());
```

Collection here:

```
public class TufinInterfaceCollection extends AbstractCollection<TufinInterface> implements ListModel<String> {
    ArrayList<TufinInterface> list=new ArrayList();
    private final ArrayList listeners=new ArrayList();

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return list.remove(o); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(TufinInterface e) {
        return list.add(e); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public TufinInterface get(int i){
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<TufinInterface> iterator() {
        return list.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
       return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getElementAt(int i) {
        return get(i).toString();
    }    

    @Override
    public void addListDataListener(ListDataListener ll) {
        this.listeners.add(ll);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListDataListener(ListDataListener ll) {
        this.listeners.remove(ll);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why dont you try it with `AbstractListModel `

Comment: AbstractListModel is not implementable,only extendable.

Comment: Just use the DefaultListModel. Changes should be made to the data in the model, not the actual collection.